# How to pass in initial value to form with select fields - React Final Form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

How to pass in initial value to form with select fields - React Final Form?

```
<Field className="input" name="pergunta_1" component="select">
<option>---</option>
<option>Sim</option>
<option>Não</option>
</Field>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your issue?

Comment: Hi.  I want to selected option 3 'Não'. But it does not go into the state

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through list of options as given below:

```
 <Field className="input" name="pergunta_1" component="select">
 <option>---</option>

 {allFieldDisplay.map((each, index) => (
 <option value={each.fieldValue} key={index}>{each.fieldName}</option>
                  ))}

 </Field>
```

Comment: Thank you.
How can I selected an item by default?

Comment: <option selected="selected">---</option>

Comment: Does not work. I want to selected option 3 'Não'. But it does not go into the state.